# How to click text to input or call a function in python

Tags: python, button

Is it possible to just click printed text, I know buttons are usable but it would be nice if I could use text or buttons that don't open a new window, I don't need to open links, just to make it call a function. I searched the internet but I'm not finding anything relevant, if you do please post the link.

Comment: What UI framework are you using. TKinter?

Comment: If you're using Tkinter, then create a button and set parameter (command=YourFucntion)

Answer (score 1):

To clarify, I assume you are asking for a way to click on the displayed text in the GUI to call a function.

- If so, you can simply store this displayed text and not display it, but rather create a button with a transparent background with the stored text as its label.

  **Maybe something like this:**

```
from tkinter import *

#Tab setup
win = Tk()
win.geometry("800x500")

#The text and button setup
displayText = "Hello World"
textButton=Button(win,text=displayText,width=20,height=2,command=FUNCTION_NAME_HERE).pack()

#Run tab
win.mainloop()
```

Comment: Hey, I don't want a button that opens in a new window, just a printed text in a console that I can click for input, but I'm not sure it's possible. Thanks anyway for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use `span`

```
<span onclick="doSomething()">Your Text</span>

function doSomething() {
   // do something
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I didn't clarify but I'd like something in python, not HTML.